# Login and LoginStatus destination URLs not working properly

Tags: c#, asp.net, url, login-control, loginstatus

The site I'm creating has one section for non authenticated users and another for authenticated users.

(almost) every page in the site has a LoginStatus control which is located in the header and shown as 2 different buttons depending on status.

The problem I have, is that with pages in the non-authenticated folders of the site despite setting the LogoutPageUrl value in that control to the value "~login.aspx", the site merely refreshes the page but the control DOES show that the user is logged out by displaying the correct image in the control..and when clicking on that control again you ARE directed to the login page.

here's that control:

```
    <asp:LoginStatus CssClass="loginControlBtn" ID="LoginStatus2" 
    runat="server" LogoutPageUrl="~/login.aspx" 
    LoginImageUrl="~/images/LoginBtn.jpg"
    LogoutImageUrl="~/images/LogoutBtn.jpg" />
```

Also, once clicking on the login option on the LoginStatus control and logging in again you aren't directed to the page specified in the Login control, but end up back at the page you were at when you selected the Login option on the LoginStaus control.

here's the code for that Login control:

```
    <asp:Login ID="helpDeskLoginCtrl" runat="server" 
            DestinationPageUrl="~/admin/HelpDeskOptions.aspx" 
            style="text-align: justify" VisibleWhenLoggedIn="False" Width="421px">
        </asp:Login>
```

The site uses Forms authentication so that only authenticated users can view pages in the "~/admin" folder..and at least THAT part is working properly as when selecting to logout whilst at a page in that folder you're directed to the "~/login.aspx" page.

But then when you login again rather than going to

```
DestinationPageUrl="~/admin/HelpDeskOptions.aspx
```

as specified in the Login control you're directed back to the page you came from.

I'm really stumped.

Comment: oh..never mind about the colours.. :)

Comment: If anyone can inform me as to how to get my code-text colourful in here for the sake of legibility (some seem to be able to manage it..) that too would be awesome. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

well one of my college teachers helped me with the actual answer to this problem, and while I can't take credit for it I'm positing it here to help others who may encounter the same problem.

The property that caused my issue is the 'LogoutAction' control.

In the version of VS i'm using (2010) the default value is "Refresh" while it need to be changed to "Redirect" in order to always go to the page specified in the "LogoutPageURL" control and to not return from whence you came after logging back in.

hope this helps someone,
Fenix

Answer (score 0):

This page should provide answers regarding the LoginStatus Class - http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.loginstatus.aspx

You need to be checking the IsAuthenticated property of the Page object.

Comment: thanks haakon. I actually had one of my college teachers help me with this today, and now understand what was and wasn't goin on. I know that that link would have helped, cause now that I know the answer it does kinda make sense, but imho Microsoft haven't given a clear explaination of the relevant property at all, and that link isn't the answer as such. I'm wondering JS, should I use the "Answer Your Question" link below? I do know the answer, and I believe posting it would benefit others faced with the same frustration..

Comment: I'm asking cause i don't know the etiquette surounding it's use and don't want to risk an even greater faux pas than using tags in titles. :)